# Flutter: How to sort ListView (data from Json) in decreasing order or alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, listview, flutter, dart

This is JSON file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "United States",
    "population": 328200000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Germany",
    "population": 83020000
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "population": 66650000
  }
]
```

I want that after press the `RaisedButton`, it will sort in order ('Country Name' => decrease; 'Country Population' => alphabetically) ([image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUBfR.jpg)). How to do that ?

This is main file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:ask/country.dart';
import 'package:ask/country_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Country> _country = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    CountryServices.getCountry().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _country = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Country')),
            body: Container(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('Country Name'),
                            onPressed: () {}, // Sort alphabetically
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('Country Population'),
                            onPressed: () {}, // Sort in decreasing order
                          ))]),
                   Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: _country.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return _listCountry(index);
                        }))
            ]))));
  }

  _listCountry(index) {
    Country country = _country[index];
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text(
              country.country,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )),
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text('${country.population}', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/sort.html) official document will provide information on how to sort.

Try out the following.

```
CountryServices.getCountry().then((value) {


    setState(() {
        _country = value;
        _country.sort((a, b) => a.population.compareTo(b.population));
    });
});
```

Note : The above code is untested. You might need to tweak a bit.

Comment: Can you pls tell me where to put this code? I try to add this [here](https://i.imgur.com/3HLzDDT.jpg) but got an error, I think I was wrong somewhere

Comment: This is error details [link](https://i.imgur.com/lTpLk18.jpg)

Comment: It worked, thanks! But how do I call this from `onPressed` of `RaisedButton`?

Comment: Great. Try a bit. If you couldn't solve the puzzle then post another question on StackOverflow. Shouldn't require though. :)

Comment: Thanks anyway, I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107557/flutter-how-to-sort-listview-by-togglebuttons), this time I want to apply the sort method to the `ToggleButtons`, it would be great if you could help me again :D