# Flutter: How to sort ListView by ToggleButtons

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view as follows:

[image]

Code of listview:

```js
_listCountry(index) {
  Country country = _country[index];
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget> [
      Text('${country.id}'),
      Text(country.name),
      Text('${country.population}'),
    ],
  );
}
```

And I created methods to sort, it worked fine:

```js
_onSortID() {
  setState(() {
    _country.sort((a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));
  });
}

_onSortName() {
  setState(() {
    _country.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
  });
}

_onSortPopulation() {
  setState(() {
    _country.sort((b, a) => b.population.compareTo(a.population));
  });
}
```

**So how do I get these methods into the `Onpressed` of `ToggleButtons` so that they can sort when pressed?** This is the Toggle Button code:

```js
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget> [
    Text('Country ID'),
    Text('Country Name'),
    Text('Country Population')
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
        if (buttonIndex == index) {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = !isSelected[buttonIndex];
        } else {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
        }
      }
    });
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,
)
```

Comment: way not use DataTable widget

Comment: Yep, because I want to customize it even more, Ex: NetworkImage, ExpansionTitle ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

Define a list of methods

```
List sortMethods;
```

Then create it in **initState()** like this :

```
@override
  initState() {
    sortMethods = List.of({
      () => setState(
            () {
              _country.sort((a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));
            },
          ),
      () => setState(() {
            _country.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
          }),
      () => setState(() {
            _country.sort((a, b) => b.population.compareTo(a.population));
          })
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

When you select **ToggleButton**, call the method like this :

```
 onPressed: (int index) {
   for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
        if (buttonIndex == index) {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = !isSelected[buttonIndex];
        } else {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
        }
         sortMethods[index]();
      }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works almost perfectly, except that `isSelected.forEach((element) => false)` doesn't seem to work, it allows for multiple buttons to be simultaneously selected while I want that mutually exclusive selection. Besides, could we add one more case: **none of the buttons selected** => sort default?

Comment: Sorry I was just trying, I'm going to modify the answer, use your code

Comment: Awesome! Now it's perfect xD. Can you help me one more case: if **unselected** Toggle Button => ListView will return to the default sort state (like when starting the app)?

Comment: Or add one more case into the `sortMethods` to call it when unselected any Toggle Button

Comment: Ok my friend, Define a integer variable named oldIndex , and Move this line out of them for " sortMethods[index]();"  , Then replace it with these two lines  sortMethods[index](oldIndex == index ? true : false);
oldIndex = index;

Comment: Now if you press the same button, it will reverse the result, but you need some changes in the code : (isReversed) => setState(
            () {
              if (isReversed)
                _country = _country.reversed.toList();
              else
                _country.sort((a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));
            },
          ),  And apply this to other methods

Comment: It seems that `reversed` is not what I want because it reverses the value instead of returning to the default sort [image](https://i.imgur.com/CHAU2L5.jpg), I'm not sure if I did it wrong somewhere, please check for me, this is code I have [edited](https://i.imgur.com/EeVYc5f.jpg) and [added](https://i.imgur.com/FE7DscD.jpg)

Comment: If you want to return the list to basic mode, you must write an "InitCountry" method and call it instead of a code "_country = _country.reversed.toList();" , So it refills the _country list again

Comment: And don't forget to move the two lines out of the "for"  https://i.imgur.com/HRptNZz.png